# React application freez after saving

Tags: node.js, reactjs

My react application freezes/is unable to respond to, clicks whenever I edit a file and save it. I have to refresh the page in order to check my changes or use the application.

Comment: Are you using `useEffect` Hook ?

Comment: Yes, also using componentDidMount on different files.

Comment: Make sure all of your useEffect hooks have a `[ ]` or `cleanup`, because will re-render non-stop and may cause you freezing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed to have solved the problem for me: stackoverflow.com/a/70495171/14987294.

The other thing you can do is upgrade your react-scripts package to the latest version.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32712311)